# Determining if a recursive sequence is converging with induction

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider this sequence

$$ a_0 = 2,$$
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac 1 a_n $$

Now to prove for convergence I simply put in values ($a_1, a_2, a_3$) and got the the sequence has this behaviour: $2, 1/2, 2, 1/2,\dots$. Now since it isn't approaching any value it shouldn't be converging.

But I would like to prove this, so I looked up how to do it and you're supposed to prove monotony and limitations of the sequence. Now to prove monotony we would have to assume that the sequence is falling or raising. But how can I do that here? Since the sequence is changing its value from <1 to >1 in every iteration what should I assume? Is there a way to solve this without the "obvious" answer?

Thank you!

Comment: It's just swapping around between $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore it isn't convergent. Q. E. D

Comment: Hint : If there was a limit, what could it be? Say $L$. Then $|a_n - L|$ has to become small enough after some time. Try to contradict $\epsilon-\delta$ for every possible $L$.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking for a proof that $2\neq\frac12$, right?

Comment: Im aware that the series isnt convergent, it is obvious because of the fact that it isnt approaching any value,but rather alternating. Now I'm not sure for what proof im looking for, I'd just like to use the standard way of solving these types of problems. First you assume a limit, than you prove that the sequence is limited and that it is monotonus. Thing is I'm not sure if that is possible on this given example, and if it is how would I start.

Comment: it can also be show that if a sequence of real numbers converges, then every subsequence will converge to the same limit. If you can find two subsequences converging to different limits, then the sequence cannot be convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve $A_n A_{n+1}=1$, take $A_n=\frac{B_{n+1}}{B_{n}}$, then
We get $B_{n+2}=B_{n}$. Next, let $B_n=x^n$, then we get $x^2=1 \implies x=\pm 1$
We can write $$B_n=P +Q(-1)^n \implies A_n=\frac{P+Q(-1)^{n+1}}{P+Q(-1)^{n}}=\frac{R+(-1)^{n+1}}{R+(-1)^{n}}.$$ $$A_0=2 \implies \frac{R-1}{R+1}=2 \implies R=-3$$
Hence $$A_n=\frac{-3-(-1)^n}{-3+(-1)^n}$$

Therefore $A_n$ does not converge but it oscillates:$2,1/2,2,1/2,...$

Comment: Just what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent if and only if
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$$
which does not hold in your case since $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n = 2 \quad\ne\quad \frac{1}{2} = \liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, then $|a_{N+1}-a_N|<\epsilon$. As $a_{2n}=2, a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|=\frac{1}{2}$$ So there is no $N$ for $\epsilon\leq\frac{1}{2}$.